# How do I breakup HTML elements in Beautifulsoup to insert them into a MySQL database table?

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping text information from a website using Beautifulsoup. How do I scrape out only select text, so that I can input the selected text to a MySQL db?

### I have tried various ways to pull text strings, but I'm not having any luck. I am getting desired output, just not sure how to eliminate the unwanted items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

html_url = 'https://www.nwk.usace.army.mil/Locations/District-Lakes/Pomme-de-Terre-Lake/Daily-Lake-Info-2/' 

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

pageNav = soup.find(class_= 'Normal')

pageSub = pageNav.find_all('p')

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    print (strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
```

---

I would like to limit and pull just four items over to a MySQL DB: Date, Yesterday's High, 24 hour low, Lake Surface Temperature. Here are my current results:

Date:      April 3, 2019
Normal Pool Elevation:   839.00
Lake Elevation:   843.53
24 Hr. Change:   +0.14'
Discharging to the  **Pomme de Terre River:**
Pomme de Terre River:   50 Cubic Feet per Second          
Air Temperature  None
Observed at 8:00 a.m.    48
Yesterday's High:  64
 24 Hour Low:  39
Lake Surface Temperature:    46 (Taken Monday and Friday at approximately 8:00 a.m.)
River Temp:         46 (Taken Monday & Friday at approximately 8:00 a.m.)
Wind None
Direction:   SE
Speed:     4
Peak:  9
Precipitation:  0.00"

Comment: Just filter the whole code with an if statement

Comment: Do you have a syntax suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

html_url = 'https://www.nwk.usace.army.mil/Locations/District-Lakes/Pomme-de-Terre-Lake/Daily-Lake-Info-2/' 

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

pageNav = soup.find(class_= 'Normal')

pageSub = pageNav.find_all('p')

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    if strong_tag.text == "24 Hr. Change:" or strong_tag.text=="Yesterday's High:" or strong_tag.text=="Date:    " or strong_tag.text=="Lake Surface Temperature:":
        print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
```

The if statement should get everything sorted. I tried this code in a jupyter notebook and it worked. The only issue here was that there are some spaces after the word date. So right now the file won't print the date line.

To hardcode the date case use this code instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

html_url = 'https://www.nwk.usace.army.mil/Locations/District-Lakes/Pomme-de-Terre-Lake/Daily-Lake-Info-2/' 

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

pageNav = soup.find(class_= 'Normal')

pageSub = pageNav.find_all('p')

date = True
for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    if date:
        print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
        date = False
    if strong_tag.text == "24 Hr. Change:" or strong_tag.text=="Yesterday's High:" or strong_tag.text=="Lake Surface Temperature:":
        print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
```

Comment: Results in same output:   Date:      April 3, 2019
Normal Pool Elevation:   839.00
Lake Elevation:   843.53
24 Hr. Change:   +0.14'
Discharging to the  <strong>Pomme de Terre River:</strong>
Pomme de Terre River:   50 Cubic Feet per Second          
Air Temperature  None
Observed at 8:00 a.m.    48
Yesterday's High:  64
 24 Hour Low:  39
Lake Surface Temperature:    46 (Taken Monday and Friday at approximately 8:00 a.m.)
River Temp:         46 (Taken Monday & Friday at approximately 8:00 a.m.)
Wind None
Direction:   SE
Speed:     4
Peak:  9
Precipitation:  0.00"

Comment: You could hardcode the date property easily though because it is the first element in the list.